# kill process and run a program in erlang

Tags: erlang

I develop a program in erlang

I run this program with this command:

```
 ./build.sh && ./deploy.sh ./erl_start.sh
```

I want know to do a **test** in the function **verify**  which are stored in the file model.erl of my program

in the function **verify**  I should find and kill the process of my program ( current program)
and I want to run the program

```
verify(Val)->
if Val =:=40 ->
%% kill the process of my program
%% run this commande ./build.sh && ./deploy.sh ./erl_start.sh

true -> ok

end.
```

so I think that I will try with

```
  verify(Val)->
    if Val =:=40 ->
  exit(Pid,Reason), %%  but I should know the pid of the current program
   os_cmd("./build.sh && ./deploy.sh ./erl_start.sh");

    true -> ok

    end.
```

knowing the pid of the current programm  --> I have an application which is running and in the code of this application I should have a way to know the pid of this application in order to make it stop

currently

I try with this function:

```
verify(Val)->
    if Val =:=40 ->
Pid = self(), 

io:format("~w~n",[Pid]),
spawn(fun() -> exit(Pid, kill) end),
    LsOut = os:cmd("./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh");

    true -> ok

    end.
```

and when I test this function I have this error :

```
1> model:verify(40).
<0.144.0>
** exception exit: killed
```

My goal is:

I have an application developed in Erlang to run this application I need to do: **./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh**

I want to make a function (in our case it is the function verify) that will do the same thing as **Ctrl + C and after do ./build.sh && ./deploy.sh && ./erl_start.sh
meanig stop the application and run again this application**

I also test your command and I have this result :

```
1> [io:format("~p : ~p~n",[Pid,erlang:process_info(Pid,current_function)]) || Pid <- processes()].
<0.0.0> : {current_function,{init,loop,1}}
<0.3.0> : {current_function,{erl_prim_loader,loop,3}}
<0.5.0> : {current_function,{gen_event,fetch_msg,5}}
<0.6.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.8.0> : {current_function,{application_master,main_loop,2}}
<0.9.0> : {current_function,{application_master,loop_it,4}}
<0.10.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.11.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.12.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.13.0> : {current_function,{global,loop_the_locker,1}}
<0.14.0> : {current_function,{global,collect_deletions,2}}
<0.15.0> : {current_function,{global,loop_the_registrar,0}}
<0.16.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.18.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.19.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.20.0> : {current_function,{code_server,loop,1}}
<0.21.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.22.0> : {current_function,{standard_error,server_loop,1}}
<0.23.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.24.0> : {current_function,{user_drv,server_loop,5}}
<0.25.0> : {current_function,{group,server_loop,3}}
<0.26.0> : {current_function,{group,server_loop,3}}
<0.27.0> : {current_function,{shell,shell_rep,4}}
<0.28.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.29.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.36.0> : {current_function,{application_master,main_loop,2}}
<0.37.0> : {current_function,{application_master,loop_it,4}}
<0.38.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.39.0> : {current_function,{gen_event,fetch_msg,5}}
<0.40.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.41.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.44.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.45.0> : {current_function,{mnesia_locker,loop,1}}
<0.46.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.47.0> : {current_function,{mnesia_tm,doit_loop,1}}
<0.48.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.49.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.53.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.54.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.63.0> : {current_function,{disk_log,loop,1}}
<0.65.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.66.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.67.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.68.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.69.0> : {current_function,{mnesia_late_loader,loop,1}}
<0.105.0> : {current_function,{application_master,main_loop,2}}
<0.106.0> : {current_function,{application_master,loop_it,4}}
<0.107.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.108.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.109.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.110.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.111.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.112.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.113.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.114.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.115.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.117.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.118.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.119.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.120.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.121.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.123.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.124.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.125.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.126.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.127.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.129.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.130.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.131.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.132.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.133.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.135.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.136.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.137.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.138.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.139.0> : {current_function,{prim_inet,accept0,2}}
<0.140.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
<0.143.0> : {current_function,{os,start_port_srv_loop,2}}
<0.144.0> : {current_function,{erl_eval,do_apply,5}}
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
 ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]
```

and with the second command I have :

```
1> [io:format("~p : ~p~n",[Pid,erlang:process_info(Pid,initial_call)]) || Pid <- processes()]. 
<0.0.0> : {initial_call,{otp_ring0,start,2}}
<0.3.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.5.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.6.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.8.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.9.0> : {initial_call,{application_master,start_it,4}}
<0.10.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.11.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.12.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.13.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.14.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.15.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.16.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.18.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.19.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.20.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.21.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.22.0> : {initial_call,{standard_error,server,2}}
<0.23.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.24.0> : {initial_call,{user_drv,server,2}}
<0.25.0> : {initial_call,{group,server,3}}
<0.26.0> : {initial_call,{group,server,3}}
<0.27.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.28.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.29.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.36.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.37.0> : {initial_call,{application_master,start_it,4}}
<0.38.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.39.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.40.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.41.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.44.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.45.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.46.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.47.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.48.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.49.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.53.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.54.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.63.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.65.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.66.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.67.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.68.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.69.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.105.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.106.0> : {initial_call,{application_master,start_it,4}}
<0.107.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.108.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.109.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.110.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.111.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.112.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.113.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.114.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.115.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.117.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.118.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.119.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.120.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.121.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.123.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.124.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.125.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.126.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.127.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.129.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.130.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.131.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.132.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.133.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.135.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.136.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.137.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.138.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.139.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.140.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.143.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.144.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
 ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exit(Pid, Reason) and then [os_cmd/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1) function to execute your commands.

If you want to restart the vm, erl should be started with -heart and use init:reboot to restart the vm

Comment: but how can I know the pid of the program ,

Comment: using: [erlang:self/0](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#self-0), but then the program will kill itself and the [os:cmd/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1) will never be run?

Comment: you can spawn another process which does it for you

Comment: Pid = self(), spawn(fun() -> exit(Pid, kill) end).  I think you should  read some tutorial about Erlang. http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ is a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can know what are the pids of processes running within a virtual machine using the function `erlang:processes()`. Then using `erlang:process_info/1 or /2` you can get information about current function, initial caller...

for example called from the shell you can print:

```
1> [io:format("~p : ~p~n",[Pid,erlang:process_info(Pid,current_function)]) || Pid <- processes()].
<0.0.0> : {current_function,{init,loop,1}}
<0.3.0> : {current_function,{erl_prim_loader,loop,3}}
<0.5.0> : {current_function,{gen_event,fetch_msg,5}}
<0.6.0> : {current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}}
...
```

or:

```
2> [io:format("~p : ~p~n",[Pid,erlang:process_info(Pid,initial_call)]) || Pid <- processes()].    
<0.0.0> : {initial_call,{otp_ring0,start,2}}
<0.3.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
<0.5.0> : {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
<0.6.0> : {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}}
```

if you replace the io:format/2 by your killing function filtering on the correct initial caller, it could do the trick.

Beside this, I don't fully understand what you intend to do. Generally, wen a process is killed, the VM is not stopped, unless you write some code for this (I never tried but it should be feasible). In this case, you should restart the VM using the opion -heart and the init:reboot as @Vinod said.

But the usual way to control and restart processes is to use supervisor trees inside the VM
. You can then tune the restart strategy in order to have a good reliability but also a good service. Again, as @Vinod said, the site [learnyousomeerlang.com](http://learnyousomeerlang.com) is your friend. You will find almost all you need to write OTP compliant applications.